# Alternatives to acetate?

Tags: equipment

What are some alternatives to using acetate strips?  I'm not interested in a specific application here, so feel free to give ideas for all types of techniques.  Under what culinary circumstances, if any, can they be substituted with a silpat?  Parchment paper?  Other types of plastic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rarely. Acetates are usually used when you need a thin, flexible backing for whatever you're making. Silpats aren't nearly as flexible, and don't have a uniformly smooth surface; you will impart a texture to whatever you're making. And you can't really cut them into whatever shape you want. Parchment paper doesn't have the strength of acetate; you can't make rings out of it. Plus it will absorb some liquid, lowering its strength further.